# Case Select Logic

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get this case to work and it's not displaying the output I was hoping for...

**INPUT VALUE:**

`123456     DUPL`

**CODE**

```
Select Case Cells(i, 5).value
   Case InStr(Cells(i, 5).value, "DUPL") = True
      Debug.Print ediData.EDINumber & " = DUPL"
End Select
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

`123456 = DUPL`

**EDIT:**

What is the proper usage for this `Select Case` statement to get the proper output I'm looking for

Comment: Why'd I get a down vote for this? It's concise and to the point and requests a proper answer

Comment: Not my downvote, but rather unclear what the question/problem is. "not displaying the output I was hoping for" - and exactly what is that?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I suppose that's a valid reason... Edited to be more clear as to what the question is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use Select case in this you must use True in the Select Case line.

Instr returns a number not a Boolean, 0 for not found and >0 for the relative location in the string when found:

```
Select Case True
   Case InStr(Cells(i, 5).value, "DUPL") > 0
      Debug.Print ediData.EDINumber & " = DUPL"
End Select
```

Which is like If:

```
If InStr(Cells(i, 5).value, "DUPL") > 0 Then
    Debug.Print ediData.EDINumber & " = DUPL"
End If
```

Or you could do this:

```
Select Case InStr(Cells(i, 5).value, "DUPL")
   Case Is > 0
      Debug.Print ediData.EDINumber & " = DUPL"
End Select
```

Comment: Alright, I'll have another question added on to this shortly, to finalize this portion of my code which will come soon. Thanks for the hasty response!

Comment: Seems that the first solution you provided will work best, as I will need to check for other strings within the cell values. Which also in turn will answer my next question I had too :)

Comment: Then the second will work also as you can use `ElseIf` to do the other comparisons.